# jQuery - Can't get blind effect in a Rails form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a **Ruby on Rails 4** project, i'm trying to use **jQueryUI method show with blind effect in a form_for**. The problem here is that my form will appear as expected, but the effect will not work properly. When ever I check the checkbox, the targeted div will eventually appear, but in a weird way: at first some empty space will pop-up in its place, and after 1 sec **the whole div with its' content will appear**.

**Here is my html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@reserva) do |f| %>
    <% if @reserva.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@reserva.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this reserva from being saved:</h2>
             <ul>
                <% @reserva.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
     </div>
    <% end %>
     <div class="span12 field-box">
        <%= f.label :cliente_id %>
        <% clientes_array = Cliente.all.map { |cliente| ["#{cliente.nombre} #{cliente.apellido}", cliente.id] } %>
        <%= f.select(:cliente_id, options_for_select(clientes_array)) %>
    </div>
    <div class="span12 field-box">
        <label >Cliente Nuevo?</label>
        <%= check_box_tag 'con_cliente', 'ClienteNuevo', false %>
    </div>

    <div id="cliente_form">
        <%= f.fields_for :cliente, @cliente do |cliente_builder| %>
                  <div class="span12 field-box">
                    <label>Nombre:</label>
                    <%= cliente_builder.text_field(:nombre, class: "span9") %><br />
                </div>
```

**The javascript here:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cliente_form").hide();
        $("#con_cliente").bind('change', function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $("#cliente_form").show("blind");
            }
            else{
                $("#cliente_form").hide("blind");
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue, the problem was that bootstrap and the jquery-ui have conflicts between them, and the effect can't appear as expected.